# Why the 3M Zero Rate is not equal to the 3M Cash Rate? On Bloomberg yield curve bootstrapping

Tags: yield-curve, bootstrapping

Can someone explain to me why the 3M Zero Rate is not equal to the 3M Cash Rate?
Thanks.
[image][image]

Comment: Did you ask the help desk?

Comment: Doesn't the difference stem from the difference in conventions (day count, compounding, ...) between the Market Rate and the Zero Rate?

Answer (score 9):

Market Rate, for this particular case, is a rate quoted on ACT/360 basis, start date = 21/06/2022, end date = 21/09/2022 on ACT/360 basis means year fraction 92/360. Discount Factor is $1/(1+92/360*2.02957\%)=0.99484008$. Zero rate is continous rate on ACT/365 basis, therefore $ZR=-ln(0.99484008)/(92/365)=2.05244\%$